# How to get the physical path of a IIS virtual directory on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a virtual directory on IIS7 that is pointing to a folder inside my application root. I have some files there and I need my asp.net application reads and lists those files. How can I do that? Is there any way to know which is the real physical path of a virtual directory from asp.net? 
I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx)

```
string physicalFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/path/relative/to/my/app");
```